# Lowercasing all directories under a directory

Tags: command-line, directory, rename

I want to lowercase every directories' name under a directory. With which commands can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All the directories at one level, or recursively?

### Zsh

At one level:

```
autoload zmv
zmv -o-i -Q 'root/(*)(/)' 'root/${1:l}'
```

Recursively:

```
zmv -o-i -Q 'root/(**/)(*)(/)' 'root/$1${2:l}'
```

Explanations: `zmv` renames files matching a pattern according to the given replacement text. `-o-i` passes the `-i` option to each `mv` command under the hood (see below). In the replacement text, `$1`, `$2`, etc, are the successive parenthesized groups in the pattern. `**` means all (sub)*directories, recursively. The final `(/)` is not a parenthesized group but a glob qualifier meaning to match only directories. `${2:l}` converts `$2` to lowercase.

### Portable

At one level:

```
for x in root/*/; do mv -i "$x" "$(printf %s "$x" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"; done
```

The final `/` restricts the matching to directories, and `mv -i` makes it ask for confirmation in case of a collision. Remove the `-i` to overwrite in case of a collision, and use `yes n | for …`. to not be prompted and not perform any renaming that would collide.

Recursively:

```
find root/* -depth -type d -exec sh -c '
    t=${0%/*}/$(printf %s "${0##*/}" | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]");
    [ "$t" = "$0" ] || mv -i "$0" "$t"
' {} \;
```

The use of `-depth` ensures that deeply nested directories are processed before their ancestors. The name processing relies on there being a `/`; if you want to call operate in the current directory, use `./*` (adapting the shell script to cope with `.` or `*` is left as an exercise for the reader).

### Perl rename

Here I use the Perl rename script that Debian and Ubuntu ship as `/usr/bin/prename` (typically available as `rename` as well). At one level:

```
rename 's!/([^/]*/?)$!\L/$1!' root/*/
```

Recursively, with bash ≥4 or zsh:

```
shopt -s globstar  # only in bash
rename 's!/([^/]*/?)$!\L/$1!' root/**/*/
```

Recursively, portably:

```
find root -depth -type d -exec rename -n 's!/([^/]*/?)$!\L/$1!' {} +
```

Comment: At least on OS X this will fail if any directories are already lower case: `mv -i a a` give "mv: rename a to a/a: Invalid argument".

Comment: @Janus: Right, you get an error message, which is ugly (though harmless at the command line). But anyway I should have used zmv, which takes care of this case.

Comment: I then found about `-execdir` which is awesome: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5412/lowercasing-all-directories-under-a-directory/494262#494262 I then found that it has some `PATH` madness and was sad :-(

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a single command that will do that, but you can do something like this:

```
for fd in */; do
  #get lower case version
  fd_lower=$(printf %s "$fd" | tr A-Z a-z)
  #if it wasn't already lowercase, move it.
  [ "$fd" != "$fd_lower" ] && mv "$fd" "$fd_lower"
done
```

If you need it to be robust, you should account for when there is already two directories that differ only in case.

As a one-liner:

```
for fd in */; do fd_lower=$(printf %s "$fd" | tr A-Z a-z) && [ "$fd" != "$fd_lower" ] && mv "$fd" "$fd_lower"; done
```

Comment: This showed up midway through my writing the (basically the same) suggestion: `for file in * ; do if [ -d "$file" ] ; then dest="$(echo $file | sed y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/)" ; [ "$dest" != "$file" ] && mv "$file" "$dest" ; fi ; done`

Comment: I was trying to work it out with `find -type d`, but couldn't quite get it

Comment: My instinct would have been to do `for fd in */;`, thus avoiding the need for the check if it was a directory, but I have no idea if this instinct was a good one.

Comment: Yep, for...*/ would be better.

Comment: @Shawn: `tr` already expects a range, so `tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` translates `[` to `[` and `]` to `]` in passing. This is useless but harmlesss; however without the quotes the shell would expand the brackets if there was a file with a one-uppercase-letter name in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I took this as a one-liner challenge :)  First, establish a test case:

```
$ for d in foo Bar eVe; do mkdir -p dcthis/$d; touch dcthis/a${d}.txt; done
$ ls dcthis/
Bar     aBar.txt    aeVe.txt    afoo.txt    eVe     foo
```

I use `find` to spot the directories with uppercase letters and then downcase them via `sh -c 'mv {} echo {} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]'`. Guess using `sh -c` is a bit hack-ish, but my head always explodes when I try escaping things for `find` directly.

```
$ (cd dcthis && find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -path '*[A-Z]*' -exec sh -c 'mv {} `echo {} | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]`' \;)
$ ls dcthis/
aBar.txt    aeVe.txt    afoo.txt    bar     eve     foo
```

Be warned: This solution does not check whether downcasing leads to collisions!

Comment: checking for collisions is easy: `mv -i`. A bigger problem is that you haven't used proper quoting, so your command will fail if there are special characters (whitespace or `\[*?`) anywhere in the name. There's no point of using `find` unless recursing, and then you need `find -depth`, and `-path` must be `-name`. See my answer for working examples.

Comment: @Giles. Thanks! I saw your `mv -i` after writing this. Good point with the quoting...

Answer (score 0):

**`find -execdir rename`**

This renames files and directories with a regular expression affecting only basenames.

So for a prefix you could do:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -depth -execdir rename 's/(.*)/\L$1/' '{}' \;
```

or to affect files only:

```
PATH=/usr/bin find . -type f -execdir rename 's/(.*)/\L$1/' '{}' \;
```

`-execdir` first `cd`s into the directory before executing only on the basename.

I have explained it in more detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541582/find-multiple-files-and-rename-them-in-linux/54163971#54163971